# Mongoose structure for multi language

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a problem to have a clear idea to structure my model to be able to handle multi languages.
Let's say we have a Schema **User**:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: { 
    en: { ... },
    fr: { ... },
 }
})
```

Now let's say in the Frontend the user changes the default language of the application, i want to be able to return to user only the result corresponding to that selected language.

ex: if he picks EN i will return only firstName in EN

- How should I handle that ?
- Can this schema be better ?
- Let's say we have other schema that have the same process how to set default language for all schema to pick the corresponding property depending on selected language ?
- Where should i store the selected language ? as a header for example ?

Thank you guys.

Comment: That is one of the right-way for real-time project as well

Answer (score -1):

you can just make your  model like this

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
   firstName: { 
    en: { ... },
    fr: { ... },
   }
   default_language: en
  })
```

when you want to change the language update user.default_language
whan you want to display first_name with that langauge you can do like this (mode code is with mongoose).

```
let userLanguage=User.findById(userid).select("default_language");
let user=User.findById(userid);
firstname=user.firstname.userLanguage.default_language;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, but I can't help but wonder if this is really the most future-proof way of going about this. Isn't there a way of doing this with so-called "directives", at least in Apollo Server?